# Return call after the radio button or check box is clicked in jquery or javascript or angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the call back after the click has been completed in the original function.

```
<input type="radio" onchange="changefun()" />
function changefun()
{
   // some code will be done here
}
```

on other page

```
$(document).on('input:radio','click',function(e){
    // success means after the changefun() has completed
    if(e.success)
    {
      // some code
    }else{
      // some code
    }
}
```

Do we have anything like this in jquery

Comment: How is that question relevant to angularjs?!

Comment: why not call the 'input:radio','click'.... handler at the end of changeFun?if you need reference var this inside it you can use call,apply.

Comment: If we have anything related to angular also it is fine, that's why added angular

Comment: @techie_28 there are lot many files we need to change, i want a global solution to fix it.

Comment: It's the most unrelated angularjs question on SO. Your event binding should be `$(document).on('click', 'input:radio',function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help and solve your problem. Let me know.

```js
function changefun() {
    alert("Change Called");
}
               
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e){
  
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    {
      alert("Success");
    }
    else
      {
        alert("Fail");
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
<input type="radio" onchange="changefun1()" >Select</input>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No that is not my requirement, once the function get called need a response back to the document click

Comment: once changeFun has been completed i need to get back a call again to $document click event